# httpWebRequest pass and get parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I trying to send parameters by GET request to my web api method like this:

```
somesite.com/api/somesection/v1/someaction?val1=1&val2=2
```

headers:
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

And my api method is:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/somesection/v1/someaction")]
public void someaction(ModelParams p)
{
    //do some action
}
```

And "ModelParams" is:

```
public class ModelParams
    {
        [Required]
        public string val1{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string val2{ get; set; }
    }
```

I get the model = null in service. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that the parameters are null in the controller, then you probably just need to add the `[FromUri]` attribute to the action, like so:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("aapi/somesection/v1/someaction")]
public void someaction([FromUri]ModelParams p)
{
    //do some action
}
```